# Повторное использование потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть поток реализованный следующим образом, при создании потока isRun=true, при выполнении определённых действий он зацикливается на sleep(), до того как изменится переменная isRun. Вопрос заключается в том, возможно ли это организовать без sleep()?. Так как много ресурсов отнимает поток во время этого зацикливания.

```
 class UpdateThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRun) {
           // выполняю определённые действия
              isRun=false;
                while (!isRun){ // зацикливаю поток, до внешнего изменения переменной
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html):

```
public synchronized void guardedJoy() {
    // This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
    // be the event we're waiting for.
    while(!joy) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
}
```

Comment: То есть обязателен ещё 1н класс с этим методом, который будет объявляться в run(). Из вне обновлять с помощью  notifyAll()?

Comment: Необязательно ещё один класс и необязательно ещё один метод, можно просто объявить синхронизованный блок внутри run. А notify при измегении флага вызывать надо, да.

Comment: @SergeyGomostaev там где ставлю notify тоже необходимо синхронизировать?

Comment: Да, нужно синхронизировать.